# Why/When would I want to use a class data member without defining an object of the class?

Tags: c++, class, data-members

It is possible in C++ to use a data member of a class without defining an object of that class, by defining that data member in the public section as a `static` variable, as in the code sample below. The question is, why/when would I want to do this? and how can I do it?

```
class ttime{
public:
    ttime(int h=0, int m=0, int s=0):hour(h), minute(m), second(s){}   //constructor with default intialization
    int& warning(){return hour;}
    void display()const{cout<<hour<<"\t";}
    static int hello; 
    ~ttime(){}

private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};


main()
{
    ttime:: hello=11310; //Is this the way to use hello without creating an object of the class?
    cout << ttime:: hello;

    ttime hi(9); 
    hi.display();
    hi.warning()++;//the user is able to modify your class's private data, which is really bad! You should not be doing this!
    hi.display();
}
```

Comment: Yes, `static` member variables are possible, and they are accessible without an object instance.  Why you would want them is a pretty broad topic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cited before, static member variables work as 'global' variables, but within the class namespace.
So it is useful for counters or shared resources between objects.

In the case of 'public static' modifier, it is easy to see its use within libraries to provide access to constants and general-purpose functionality (static methods).

For example, an input library might have:

```
class KeyEvent
{
    public:
      static const int KEY_DOWN = 111;
      static const int KEY_UP = 112;
      ...
}

//And then in your code
#include <KeyEvent>

void poolEvent(Key *key)
{
    if(key->type() == KeyEvent::KEY_DOWN)
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a class member variable as `static` essentially makes it a singleton object that is shared by all of the instances of that class. This is useful for things like counters, semaphores and locks, and other  types of data that need to be shared by the other class members.

Declaring it `public` makes it accessible to all users of that class. It's generally a bad idea to allow class variables to be modifiable by functions outside the class, though.

Declaring it `const`, on the other hand, is the usual way to provide publicly readable constants for the class.

**Example**

Your library class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // Version number of this code
    static const int    VERSION = 1;

private:
    // Counts the number of active Foo objects
    static int          counter = 0;

public:
    // Constructor
    Foo()
    {
        counter++;     // Bump the instance counter
        ...
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Foo()
    {
        counter--;     // Adjust the counter
        ...
    }
};
```

Some client of your library:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Bar()
    {
        // Check the Foo library version
        if (Foo::VERSION > 1)
            std::cerr << "Wrong version of class Foo, need version 1";
        ...
    }
};
```

In this example, `VERSION` is a static constant of the class, which in this case informs the outside world what version of the code is contained in the class. It's accessed by the syntax `Foo::VERSION`.

The static `counter` variable, on the other hand, is private to the class, so only member functions of `Foo` can access it. In this case, it's being used as a counter for the number of active `Foo` objects.

Comment: useful, but still "why would someone want to use a data member of a class without defining an object of that class and how is such thing done?"

Comment: Because the class member might be of some other type, and be used for a purpose different from (but related to) objects of the class type itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the c++ syntax for statics at the moment. But in c++-cli (.net, Visual C++) the `::` is correct.
For the purpose of statics:
There are many cases where it makes sense to use them. In general, when you want to store information that belong to the class itself (meaning to all objects of the class) and not to a single object/instance.

Answer (score 1):

Even though not originally invented for this purpose, `static` `constexpr` data members of `structs` are a backbone of template meta-programming.  Just check out the [`limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) standard library header as a simple example.

For example, we can define a wrapper around the builtin `sizeof` operator.  While rather useless in itself, it hopefully gives the right idea.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Calipers
{
  static constexpr auto size = sizeof(T);
};

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "short:   " << Calipers<short>::size   << "\n";
  std::cout << "int:     " << Calipers<int>::size     << "\n";
  std::cout << "long:    " << Calipers<long>::size    << "\n";
  std::cout << "float:   " << Calipers<float>::size   << "\n";
  std::cout << "double:  " << Calipers<double>::size  << "\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
short:   2
int:     4
long:    8
float:   4
double:  8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to a global variable, only that it is not defined at the global namespace.

You find it in C++ code that was written before namespaces were introduced, or in template meta programming were it is more useful.

In general, I would not recommend to use it as in your example and would prefer to avoid global state as much as possible. Otherwise, you end up with code that is difficult to test.